# How to check which localization strings are really used in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, internationalization, translation

We have a legacy application for iOS translated to two languages. After checking the localization files we realized, that there are a lot of strings that are not really used in the application, though, we cannot be sure which ones.

Is there some way (maybe some utility) that can check objective-c project and localization files and check which strings re really in use and which are not so we can delete the from the localization files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `genstrings` to generate a new strings file from your project and then use one of the string-files comparison/merge tools to find the differences.